# Receiving and empty list when trying to make a webscraper to parse websites for links

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml

I was reading [this](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/) website and learning how to make a webscraper with `lxml` and `Requests. This is the webscraper code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

web_page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')

tree = html.fromstring(web_page.content)


buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')

print "These are the buyers: ", buyers
print "And these are the prices: ", prices
```

It works as intended, but when I try to scrape https://www.reddit.com/r/cringe/ for all the links I'm simply getting `[]` as a result:

```
#this code will scrape a Reddit page

from lxml import html
import requests


web_page = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/cringe/")

tree = html.fromstring(web_page.content)

links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="data-url"]/text()')

print links
```

What's the problem with the xpath I'm using? I can't figure out what to put in the square brackets in the xpath

Comment: Where do you get @class="data-url"

Comment: @DanielLee When you hover over a link on reddit and inspect the element you can see `data-url` in the `div` block of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your xpath is wrong, there are no classes with *data-url*, it is an *attribute* so you would want `div[@data-url]` and to extract the attribute you would use  `/@data-url`:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"}
web_page = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/cringe/", headers=headers)

tree = html.fromstring(web_page.content)

links = tree.xpath('//div[@data-url]/@data-url')

print links
```

Also you may see html like the following returned if you query too often or don't use a user-agent so respect what they recommend:

```
<p>we're sorry, but you appear to be a bot and we've seen too many requests
from you lately. we enforce a hard speed limit on requests that appear to come
from bots to prevent abuse.</p>

<p>if you are not a bot but are spoofing one via your browser's user agent
string: please change your user agent string to avoid seeing this message
again.</p>

<p>please wait 6 second(s) and try again.</p>

    <p>as a reminder to developers, we recommend that clients make no
    more than <a href="http://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API">one
    request every two seconds</a> to avoid seeing this message.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you plan on scraping a lot of reddit, you may want to look at [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) has a nice introduction to *xpath* expressions.

To break it down:

```
//div[@data-url]
```

searches the doc for *div's* that have an attribute `data-url` we don't care what the attribute value is, we just want the div.

That just finds the *div's*, if you removed the */@data-url* you would end up with a list of elements like:

```
[<Element div at 0x7fbb27a9a940>, <Element div at 0x7fbb27a9a8e8>,..
```

`/@data-url`  actually extracts the *attrbute value* i.e the *hrefs*.

Also  you just wanted specific links, the *youtube* links you could filter using *contains*:

```
'//div[contains(@data-url, "www.youtube.com")]/@data-url'
```

`contains(@data-url, "www.youtube.com")` will check if the *data-url* attribute values contain *www.youtube.com* so the output will be a list of the *youtube* links.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, I knew what I put was wrong. Was just trying anything I guess, I knew how to refer to `data-url` but wasn't sure how to actually extract the information from it.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further the `/data-url` portion? Up until that part I know what's happening, we're selecting all of the `div` elements that contain the `data-url` attribute. But after that it looks like we're selecting the child of `data-url` which is just itself? Also thanks for that tip about the user-agent

Comment: @Amon, I added a little more explanation, `/@data-url` extracts the attribute value.  `@` signifies it is an attribute we are looking for. If it were the text we wanted we would just use `/text()`